# How to pass high current through photo interrupter sensor

Tags: coil

I am currently trying to build a coil gun that uses a high current to create a strong electromagnetic attraction. I'm using a photointerrupter sensor to detect when the projectile begins to leave the coil and want to use it as a switch. If nothing is interrupting the sensor, the current will flow through and power the coil but if the projectile is blocking the sensor, current should no longer flow through. However, an issue I have come upon is that photo-interrupter sensors are only able to have very small amounts of current pass through them so if I use the amount of current that I need to power the coil it burns out the sensor. Does anyone have any possible solutions or ways to approach this problem? Any help is appreacited.

Comment: You don't. You pass a small current through the sensor, and into a current amplifier.

Comment: A long time ago people invented relays and transistors. They use a small current, or voltage in the case MOSFETs to control large currents. Draw or describe the currents and number of coils involved and you will get more help.